# AppBar en Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation-drawer

Hola a todos quisiera saber como podria trabajar en la parte que esta encerrada, ya que al crear un AppBar, se crea el que esta en Verde. Quiero trabajar en el azul sin afectar al NavigationDrawer cuando se abran las demas pantallas. No se si deba de cambiar el NavigationDrawer, o la forma en que abro las pantallas, ya que no quiero que se vea empalmado como en la Primera Imagen.

[image: Primer Imagen]

Esta es la pantalla que se muestra en la primera imagen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class principal extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Menu'),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        ),
      );
}
```

Este es el NavigationDrawer

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/acercade.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/principal.dart';
import 'corarioch.dart';
import 'corariog.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeState createState() => HomeState();
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int _selectDrawerItem = 0;

  _getDrawerItemWidget(int pos) {
    switch (pos) {
      case 0:
        return principal();
      case 1:
        return corariog();
      case 2:
        return corarioch();
      case 3:
        return acercade();
    }
  }

  _onSelectItem(int pos) {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    setState(() {
      _selectDrawerItem = pos;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              accountName: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "PIBEDS",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              accountEmail: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Cantos de la Iglesia',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              currentAccountPicture: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/pibedslogopng.png'),
                      radius: 35),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 15),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Home'),
              leading: Icon(Icons.home),
              selected: (0 == _selectDrawerItem),
              onTap: () {
                _onSelectItem(0);
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 15),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Corario Grande'),
              leading: Icon(Icons.book),
              selected: (1 == _selectDrawerItem),
              onTap: () {
                _onSelectItem(1);
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 15),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Corario Chico'),
              leading: Icon(Icons.book),
              selected: (2 == _selectDrawerItem),
              onTap: () {
                _onSelectItem(2);
              },
            ),
            Divider(),
            const SizedBox(height: 15),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Acerca de'),
              leading: Icon(Icons.info),
              selected: (3 == _selectDrawerItem),
              onTap: () {
                _onSelectItem(3);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: _getDrawerItemWidget(_selectDrawerItem),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Segunda Pantalla]

Segunda Pantalla

En esta también quiero trabajar en la parte azul sin afectar la primer pantalla, ya que hare cosas diferentes con las diferentes pantallas.

Comment: La verdad es que no entiendo qué quieres hacer o cuál es tu problema, pero creo que tienes dos Scaffold en la misma pantalla y eso no pinta nada bien. Deberías tener solo 1 por pantalla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo mejor que puedes hacer es crear tu propio Widget de AppBar, de este modo puedes modificar lo que desees sin tener problemas con el drawer. Tambien puedes gestionar manualmente los botones de retroceso.

Comment: ¿Como se crearía lo que comentas?, te sugerimos revisar [answer] y editar tu publicación,. saludos.

Answer (score 0):

creo que lo que puedes hacer para que no te aparezca las 2 AppBar es trabajar con 1 solo pero que sea dinamico, por ejemplo ahi usas Switch, podrias hacer la funcion que al darle click en cada opcion, el nombre se muestre en el nav, no tengo mucha idea de como plantearlo aun pero lo que si podria sugerirte es que en tu main.dart retornes tus demas vistas o tu vista principal, algo así.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/principal.dart'; //importe

class principal extends StatelessWidget {
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Menu'),
      centerTitle: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
    ),
      //Vista Principal
      home: Home() o HomeState(),
  );
}
```

Aunque bueno lo mejor en esos casos es manejarlo por rutas,
Lo otro que podrias hacer es primero mostrar el AppBar Verde y estilizarlo o que tomara el color del Appbar Azul e intentar jugar ahi con el diseño.